# NP Arrays Used in Calculating R-Squared from Linear Regression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, correlation

I'm not seeing this clearly. Suppose i have the following function with arrays (required in function) of X and Y of shape (366,1) each.

```
 def rsquared(X, Y): #arrays
     """ Return R^2 where x and y are array-like."""

     slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = sp.stats.linregress(X, Y)
     return r_value**2

 print(rsquared(X,Y))
```

I'm trying to print the r-squared value and I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-912-af88c88367fe>", line 6, in <module>
print(rsquared(X,Y))

File "<ipython-input-912-af88c88367fe>", line 4, in rsquared
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = sp.stats.linregress(X, Y)

File "C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site- 
packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py", line 116, in linregress
ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

It looks like the code is expecting X and Y to be of shape (366, ) vs (366,1). If yes, then how do i remove the unwanted column?

Here is the first 4 rows of the X array variable and the Y variable looks similar. Thank you for any help.

```
X
array([[ 3.06833333],
       [ 7.93583333],
       [ 8.00458333],
       [11.06458333],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to pass single dimension `X` and `Y` to avoid the error:

```
print(rsquared(X[:,0],Y[:,0]))
```

Comment: Terrific - thank you for your insight - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit different from sklearn, so one solution is to transpose it in the function:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np 
def rsquared(X, Y): #arrays
     slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = sp.stats.linregress(X.T,Y.T)
     return r_value**2

np.random.seed(111)
X = np.random.uniform(0,1,(50,1))
Y = np.random.uniform(0,1,(50,1))
print(rsquared(X,Y))

0.07042849841609072
```